# `node --inspect --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead in visual-studio-2015

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I have installed nodeJs and setup on my machine with VS 2015. When I try to run the sample hello world application, its throwing the below error:

verb(node:14096) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead. Press any key to continue...

Comment: Please help me to resolve this and running the application.

Ganesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need VS 2017 to use the newer `inspect` debug protocol in Node 8.

You may need move back to Node 6 which supports the `--debug` and `--debug-brk` options.